# Invalid read of size 1 Valgrind error

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

In my program, the function `read_commands` just gets 2 strings and puts it into the struct `Commands` and returns the filled struct.
Apparently I have some fault in my logic. I'm getting the error:

> Invalid read size of 1

In valgrind.

```
typedef struct{  
Command *test  
Command *compile
}Commands;


typedef struct Command{  
char *command;  
struct Command *next;
}Command;
```

I just do `read_commands("abc", "abc");`

The rest of my code:

```
Commands read_commands(const char *compile_cmds, const char *test_cmds) {
  Commands commands;
  Command *compile, *test;
  int i;              
  if (compile_cmds == NULL || test_cmds == NULL)
     exit(0);

  compile = commands.compile;
  test = commands.test;

  i = 0;
  while (compile_cmds + i != NULL) {
    compile = malloc(sizeof(Command));
    compile->command = malloc(strlen((compile_cmds + i) + 1));
    strcpy(compile->command, compile_cmds + i);
    compile = compile->next;
    i++;
  }
  i = 0;
  while (test_cmds + i != NULL) {
    test = malloc(sizeof(Command));
    test->command = malloc(strlen((test_cmds + i) + 1));
    strcpy(test->command, test_cmds + i);
    test = test->next;
    i++;
  }
  return commands;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the exact valgrind output? It should point to a particular line of code.

Comment: @kaylum so instead of compile = compile->next;

Comment: I should do compile->next = malloc and then compile = compile->next is what you are saying

Comment: valgrind points to strcpy first and then the line above

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to do. For example `while (compile_cmds + i != NULL)`, that iterates over the same string repeatedly but with one less character each time. That is, first iteration copies "abc", second "bc", third "c". I'm guessing that is not what you want to do. And then you return  `commands` at the end. But `commands` is never initialised anywhere with any  values!

Comment: + i on pointer should go to the next string in the array it just happens to have only one string at the moment and i forgot to malloc commands i ll do it right now

Comment: No that's not right. The type is `const char *`. When you do +1 pointer arithmetic increments the pointer by the size of the type being pointed to. Which is `char` in this case with a size of 1. So it will just move to the next character in the string. Your code is a bit confused - looks like you want an array of `char *` not a single `char *`. That is, you need the type to be `const char **` so that then the +1 will indeed take you to the next entry in the array and hence the next string (assuming it is correctly passed in as an array of strings).

Comment: sorry I am quite new to C
so i should make it char **command instead char *command

Comment: Can you please post the full code so I can check myself and fix it ?

Comment: @punitvara actually apparently i have been tackling the program completely wrong.  for read_commands the char* points to a whole bunch of lines with \n breaking them apart I am thinking about how i am supposed to break the lines apart into nodes of a linked list

Comment: @user5514267 .Uptill then post the wrong code + proper val grid error screenshot .So while you update your code other can understand your code well

Comment: @punitvara i have to rewrite the whole program from scratch

Comment: Okay good luck buddy

Comment: There are lots of completely nonsensical actions in your code. `compile = commands.compile;` simply copies an uninitialized (garbage) value from `commands.compile` to `compile`. What is the point of that? If `compile_cmds` is known to be non-null, then `compile_cmds + i` can never ever be null. What is the point of `compile_cmds + i != NULL` checks in the cycle then? Also, `commands` never gets initialized. Both fields contain garbage. Your you return `commands` from your function. What is the point? Basically, it is impossible to figure out what you are trying to do from nonsensical code.

Comment: An `invalid read of size 1` can result from your attempt to *read beyond the end of an allocated block of memory* or it can result from an attempt *to read from allocated memory that has not yet been initialized with a value*. You should compile with `-g` for gdb symbol generation and then run `valgrind` again with `--leak-check=full` (or simply rerun with the symbols) and `valgrind` will give you the exact line numbers associated with your bad read. Fix it. It is a real issue that will bite you later if not corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the arguments to accept multiple commands e.g.

```
Commands read_commands(const char** compile_cmds, const char** test_cmds)
```

then you call it with:

```
char* compileCmds[] = { "abc", NULL };
char* testCmds[] = { "abc", NULL };

Commands c = read_commands(compileCmds,testCmds);
```

Meanwhile in your function to get all "compile" commands:

```
Commands commands = { NULL, NULL };
...

Command* last = NULL;
for (i = 0; compile_cmds[i] != NULL; ++i)
{
  compile = malloc(sizeof(Command));

  // check if we have added before, or if it is the first compile command
  if (last!=NULL)
  {
    // last command, so append
    last->next = compile;
  }
  else
  {
    // first command, set as first
    commands->compile = compile;
  }

  // add the payload
  compile->command = strdup(compile_cmds[i]);
  compile->next = NULL;

  // keep track of last to easy append
  last = compile;
}

...
```

you may have noticed you have duplicate code in your function, so an idea would be to create a function read_commands for one of the compile or tests at a time and call it twice instead.

e.g.

```
 read_commands(Command** cmd, const char** cmds);
 ...
 Commands c = {NULL,NULL};
 read_commands(&c.compile, compileCmds);
 read_commands(&c.test, testCmds);
```

the extra * is for to be able to change what the pointer points to

```
 read_commands(Command** pc, const char* cmds)
 {
    ... 
    *pc = malloc(sizeof(Command));
    ...
 }
```